# how to find difference between 2 sets without making change of any one?

Tags: java, set

I have 2 sets `s1` and `s2` one condition is `s1 > s2`.
And my requirement is i can't make change in `s1`. and find difference of both set we can use another set to store result.

```
Set<String> s1 = new HashSet<String>();
s1.add("a");
s1.add("b");
s1.add("c");
s1.add("n");
s1.add("d");
Set<String> s2 = new HashSet<String>();
s2.add("b");
s2.add("d");
s2.add("c");
```

i want outpur like this
like `s3= set1-set2`
output :
`s3=[a,n]`

`s1` and `s2` both are huge set above 10000 elements and in loop. so i don't want to first copy `s1` to `s3` and then remove `s2`.

Comment: While your condition is that `s1 > s2` what happens if an element exists in `s2` that is not in `s1`. Should this also be included in the result?

Comment: @radimpe That would be contrary to how standard set theory works, so I'd say no.

Comment: `s1 > s2` means that `s2` can not contain elements that are not in `s1`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this :

```
Set<String> s3 = new HashSet<String>();
for(String temp : s1){
    if(!s2.contains(temp)){
        s3.add(temp);
    }
}
for (String temp : s2) {
    if (!s1.contains(temp)) {
        s3.add(temp);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second `for` loop is unnecessary, because `s1 > s2`. `!s1.contains(temp)` will always return `false`. Revert your update back.

Comment: @orionll For this special case you are right, but the algorithm should work in any case, shouldn't it?

Comment: You don't know what the more general case is. It can be subtraction or symmetric difference.

Answer (score 3):

Using Google Guava:

```
import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

Set<String> difference = Sets.difference(s1, s2);
```

Note, that `Sets.difference` is a lazy operation. It returns a view of the difference.